# Lookahead Behaviour

Tags: regex, r, regex-lookarounds

How can you make the lookahead non-greedy?  I would like the first case not to match anything (like the second case), but it returns "winnie". I guess because it is greedily matching after the "the"?

```
str <- "winnie the pooh bear"

## Unexpected
regmatches(str, gregexpr("winnie|bear(?= bear|pooh)", str, perl=T))
# [1] "winnie"

## Expected
regmatches(str, gregexpr("winnie(?= bear|pooh)", str, perl=T))
# character(0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lookahead is being applied to `bear` in `winnie|bear(?= bear|pooh)` and not `winnie`.If you want it to apply on both use

```
(?:winnie|bear)(?= bear|pooh)
```

Now it will apply on both.
Because `winnie` matched the `ored part bear` never came into picture and neither the lookahead.

In the second case `lookahead` is applied on `winnie`.SO it fails.

Comment: Oooh and so many ✩ points ✪ already I see now ツ chai ☕ at your 50k or 100k birthday for sure!